# Meyda feature extracted dat is different in command line and through nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, feature-extraction, mfcc

I tried to extract feature of an audio file using Meyda. But feature exytracted values are different when extracted using command line meyda  and through javascript file

1. Command line

   meyda 1600153162.63571.wav mfcc

Result

> 0.057628476337413304,0.025103534166687494,-0.0033402018588145435,-0.0050914619032203364,-0.005969043107840086,-0.009452339628697326,-0.0077781823184730455,-0.0024033016732702066,-0.0033368248853514206,-0.0012372591871309979,0.00003587458387239886,0.00293735474906295,0.0033156231532707036
> 1.4306079393227265,1.3713938566968262,1.2306487569743767,1.0515807610571597,0.8414768385049735,0.6060415036630535,0.37326507523088365,0.1654296077929904,-0.015392187854876595,-0.1652509593657213,-0.27571446879975764,-0.340564139593766,-0.36505384389267703
> 9.282664122642018,6.880236029290547,3.3870794551074606,1.7170683624244123,-0.29657914336587826,-3.18544774959499,-4.433789386396694,-3.7101490665746217,-2.816738558429225,-2.2736417577176273,-1.6636438686466657,-0.8537746809738949,-0.5116463089021152
> 25.65632094501052,22.93621824737729,16.08611763344924,7.490656903754756,-0.4358888007314062,-5.641656791337735,-7.229285832273481,-5.635856022395436,-2.1681330598896817,1.5575050036371694,4.296381195632149,5.45750656573637,5.059966218569768
> 23.469876801827922,20.984500104582974,15.80549272827184,10.064116650359527,3.957435073588796,-1.75506262168123,-5.904087102697238,-8.29320895086182,-9.037630914839253,-8.230609293960022,-6.604159793447832,-4.8505887091085365,-3.2390627275186175
> 29.14206006610766,25.50517483703385,19.279159148659456,13.806566615476791,7.715092034538,2.2364700767576764,-0.8129542016331001,-2.16772108652068,-2.6257181917727093,-2.1347711722007845,-1.0689231846996041,-0.6059541306434987,-0.9955650805848651
> 12.251538716256618,9.479093353756676,5.26726325506769,2.7893618666871762,0.10288164291841367,-3.121859159330943,-4.446188894370852,-3.5959072906303837,-2.5699522942015007,-1.8300687753240275,-0.7140618177046422,0.3644613187160053,0.8353185065087604
> 18.42772721964866,15.990459244575096,11.993313228734504,9.088259023158539,6.172351883886699,2.6632784721745213,-0.2683186290158647,-1.948275236251193,-2.793271841187546,-3.305172382572076,-3.6707865100252994,-3.638999985131219,-2.863263822827715
> 15.915610973257571,13.737073178518493,9.801934620786648,5.779403187264773,1.358952752885622,-2.5086411759816647,-5.187471901991046,-7.0034704192058985,-7.837140523422115,-7.437282553994893,-6.058991955183858,-4.360246975428363,-2.680629805396066
> 15.75090683856979,13.497089898444463,9.489154494388005,5.578283842168272,1.4567586737610156,-2.141429668615224,-4.380728646793593,-5.364310654901947,-5.049848052960211,-4.214979808517224,-3.9745754014376224,-4.076571890925421,-4.020714303609834
> 23.361729244701564,20.83103985201436,16.592090051349242,12.885538444506535,8.373777248668826,2.9768227085972145,-1.399644048138661,-4.090450595665753,-5.574775136428788,-5.787457864519816,-4.693018758118676,-3.100993535744204,-1.5625546377399475
> 12.793707716744393,10.197116076581045,5.819041457288568,2.4679725003955064,-0.33041998215142393,-2.607817847380143,-4.086120143731154,-4.779218992884254,-4.374465394096245,-3.118504640745296,-1.9666020102081847,-1.5140789377241373,-1.5130647010950313
> 3.2732387410942465,2.2453286293698977,0.9749483649128511,0.472715919767034,0.11249067642678866,-0.19927487640318992,-0.24286230087509772,-0.3645480814147444,-0.5060378572115204,-0.4793996411313405,-0.45934442588699886,-0.4680761055711004,-0.2967506177492105

2. Through javscript file

   ```
      var express = require('express');
      var app = express();
      const fs = require('fs');
      var Meyda = require('meyda');
      var load = require('audio-loader')

      let filename  = "1600153162.63571.wav"
      load(filename).then(function (buffer) {
      const channelData = buffer.getChannelData(0) 
      const PaddingLength = (Math.pow(2,Math.round(Math.log2(channelData.length)+1)) - channelData.length)
      let halfPaddingLength = parseInt(PaddingLength/2)
      const pad1 = new Array(halfPaddingLength).fill(0);
      const pad2 = new Array(PaddingLength - halfPaddingLength).fill(0);
      let finalBbuffer = [...pad1,...channelData,...pad2]
      console.log(finalBbuffer.length)

      let mfccData =  Meyda.extract('mfcc', finalBbuffer)
      console.log("mfccData : ",mfccData);

     });
   ```

Result :

> [
> 249.11783051490784,
> -90.61751411189829,
> -12.253094024524968,
> 19.88245460444982,
> -11.661965456271869,
> -14.795375019626466,
> 7.19298966815922,
> 8.362884489124907,
> 3.9941283332736557,
> -3.2158388656478287,
> -2.0395393071161063,
> -0.48849176751482837,
> -3.6199623273626695
> ]

Why this difference . How to make them same ?

Answer (score 0):

They're different because you're padding the buffer in your code, whereas the command line tool is splitting your file into multiple buffers with the default buffer size and returning MFCCs for each segment.

To make them the same, you could replicate the buffer chunking that the CLI performs in your code, rather than zero-padding the whole buffer, or you could make a CLI that zero pads the input. If you do the latter, we would certainly be interested in adding that functionality to the bundled CLI, so feel free to [open an issue on our issue tracker](https://github.com/meyda/meyda/issues) to discuss if you go that route and wish to contribute.

Thanks for using Meyda!